Variants of Grothendieck section conjecture
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety defined over a field $k$. We fix the following notations : $\overline{k}$ denotes the algebraic closure of the field $k$, $X_{\overline{k}}$ denotes the variety $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}(k)} \operatorname{Spec}(\overline{k})$, $\pi_1(X)$ denotes the first étale fundamental group with a fixed chosen base point $x_0 \in X(\overline{k})$.
Consider the following two sets:

The set of $\pi_1(X_{\overline{k}})$-conjugacy classes of continuous sections of the fundamental sequence of étale fundamental groups $1 \rightarrow \pi_1(X_{\overline{k}}) \rightarrow \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k) \rightarrow 1$.

The set of $k$-rational points of the variety $X$, equivalently the set of sections of the structure map $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$.


Grothendieck section conjecture : The two sets described above are in bijection.
It is known the section conjecture does not hold in general. In particular, it is false for abelian varieties as shown in the article [M. Ciperiani, and J. Stix, Galois sections for abelian varieties over number fields]. I have the following questions.
Q1. Suppose $k$ is a number field. Is it known that the set 1 is nonempty if and only if set 2 is nonempty? One direction, that is the injectivity, is known.
Q2. There seems to be a notion of étale homotopy fixed points (see for instance § 7.3 of [K. Česnavičius, Obstructions to rational points via étale homotopy]) of the variety $X$ to be denoted by $X(hk)$ (here $h$ is for homotopy and $k$ is the ground field). Suppose $k$ is a number field. Is it known that $X(hk)$ is nonempty if and only if the set 1 is nonempty? I believe this may be known for a $K(G, 1)$-space?
For Q1 and Q2, please feel free to restrict to the situation when $X$ is a torsor under an abelian variety. Answers in more general situations are also welcome.
Q3. When $k = \mathbb{F}_q$, then the Grothendieck section conjecture is known to be true for abelian varieties as per Remark 2(4) of [M. Ciperiani, and J. Stix, Galois sections for abelian varieties over number fields]. What about other fields of characteristic $p$?
Thank you for your time. I posted this question here since it did not receive any response at stackexchange.

By definition, every Abelian variety over a field $k$ has a $k$-rational point; namely, the group identity.  Did you mean to ask these questions for a torsor under an Abelian variety rather than for an Abelian variety?

@JasonStarr Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited the question. Hopefully it is meaningful now. Please let me know if it requires further modification. Thanks!

Q1.: No this is not known. This is called the "weak section conjecture". It would imply that the finite descent obstruction suffices for hyperbolic curves. This is also unknown in full generality.

@Ben I am not sure I understand. Do you mean to say that a positive answer to question 1 for a smooth projective variety $X$ would imply that $\cap_f X(\mathbb{A}_k)^f$, where $f$ varies over all torsors $f$ under finite abelian groups equals $\overline{X(k)} \subset X(\mathbb{A}_k)$? Some more explanation or a reference would be helpful. Thank you.

A comment on Q1. which is too long for an answer. Let $k$ be a number field. What you formulated is called the "weak section conjecture" for $X/k$. This is not known in general.
However proving the weak section conjecture for all finite étale covers $Y\to X$, implies the section conjecture for $X/k$, for example see [Corollary 101, Stix, Jakob. Rational points and arithmetic of fundamental groups: Evidence for the section conjecture. Vol. 2054. Springer, 2012.]
The finite descent obstruction $X(\mathbb{A}_k)^\text{f-desc}$ is the subset of all adelic points $X(\mathbb{A}_k)$, which survive all torsors $Y\to X$ under finite étale group schemes over $K$.  Here I really mean all torsors and not just the abelian ones. (Also you would like to replace the archimedean points by the connected components but that does not matter for non-emptyness).
Let's say that the finite descent obstruction is the "the only one" for $X/k$ if the implication
$$X(\mathbb{A}_k)^\text{f-desc}\neq \emptyset\implies X(k)\neq \emptyset $$
is true. This being true for all smooth projective curves $X/k$ of genus $g\geq 1$ seems to be widely open as well. See FINITE DESCENT OBSTRUCTIONS
AND RATIONAL POINTS ON CURVES.
Jakob Stix and David Harari proved that the weak section conjecture for $X/k$, implies that finite descent obstruction is the only one for $X/k$. See [Chapter 11.3, Stix, Jakob. Rational points and arithmetic of fundamental groups: Evidence for the section conjecture. Vol. 2054. Springer, 2012.] or DESCENT OBSTRUCTION AND FUNDAMENTAL EXACT SEQUENCE.
